# How to get a new firebase ID every time

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-room

I have an app that saves a score object into Firebase Realtime Database. Said item can then be retrieved by whoever has the app downloaded.

I was using room to auto-generate the score's ID's. However, this approach fails once I add a cloud service, since different device's room will generate the same ID's and when downloaded from firebase into my room cache they will collide and overwrite each other.

To fix this I intended to create the ID's using firebase that way all the ID's can come from the same source and therefore there should be no collisions.

I found a couple of posts here detailing how to get the key from a push transaction with the firebase database. I can get the key and set it to a score item before storing it on firebase, however, when I try to make it work that way I receive the same push Key every time thus repeating the same problem I had to began with.

```
    private fun saveScore(score: Score) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        // Write a message to the database
        val database =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://winetraining-d6390-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/")
        val firebaseRef = database.getReference("Scores")

        val newPostRef = firebaseRef.push()

        val key = newPostRef.key

        if (key != null) {
            score.id = key
        }

        firebaseRef.setValue(score)
    }
}

@Entity(tableName = "table_score")
data class Score(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "score")
    var score: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "type")
    var type: Int
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Score{" +
                "score=" + score +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type=" + type +
                '}'
    }

    constructor() : this("","test-player",0,  -1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate the key you need to set some value to that key using `setValue()`

```
 val newPostRef = firebaseRef.push()
 newPostRef.setValue(someValue) // set some value to the key
```

Notice that any firebase node should be key/value pairs; keys don't stand alone without values.

You can notice that if you try to add some key manually on firebase console, it won't be kept unless you set a corresponding value.

Comment: I am doing so when I call  firebaseRef.setValue(score)  , are you saying I need to setValue before getting the key?

Comment: Yes you did that on the original firebase node not to the underlying brand new node that created by push()

Comment: I finally understood it, it ended up looking like this:    firebaseRef.push().apply {
                score.id = key.toString()
                setValue(score)
            } 
Thanks for the help